# What is the entry point Servlet of Jersey API?

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-1.0

Spring MVC/Rest has DispatcherServlet as an entry point. What is the Jersey's entry point ? 
I am asking because some exception is thrown and I don't know where from.

Answer (score 4):

Jersey analogue of Spring's `DispatchServlet` is its [`ServletContainer`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/containers/jersey-servlet-core/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletContainer.java). This is what we can configure as the application servlet, just like the `DispatchServlet` is the application servlet for Spring.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)